# SQL Nested Query - Count not returning correct results

Tags: subquery

The inner query works perfectly and gives me a count of correct and incorrect answers of a quiz  for each student, I have a student that is assigned two questions,  They have answered one question correctly and the other incorrect.

When I do a count, it shows 2 correct and 2 incorrect.

I have tried various different queries  but all end up showing the same. what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT Q.firstname, Q.lastname,  Q.Class_List_id1, COUNT((CASE WHEN Q.Correct =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Correct1, COUNT((CASE WHEN Q.Incorrect =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Incorrect1 FROM (SELECT Quiz.quiz_id AS Quiz_id1, Quiz.quiz_title, Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id, Quiz_Assign.quiz_id AS Quiz_id2, Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id, Quiz_Questions.quiz_id, Quiz_Questions.question, Quiz_Questions.option1, Quiz_Questions.option2, Quiz_Questions.option3, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id AS quiz_question_id1, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.response, Quiz_Questions.answer, Class_List.Class_List_id AS Class_List_id1, Quiz_Assign.class_list_id,(CASE WHEN Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.response=Quiz_Questions.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Correct,(CASE WHEN Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.response!=Quiz_Questions.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incorrect, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname, User_Accounts_.user_id FROM Class_List, Quiz, Quiz_Assign, Quiz_Questions, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question, User_Accounts_ WHERE (Quiz.quiz_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_id) AND (Quiz_Assign.quiz_id=16) AND (Quiz_Questions.quiz_id=Quiz.quiz_id) AND (Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id=Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id) AND (Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_assign_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id) AND (Class_List.Class_List_id=Quiz_Assign.class_list_id) AND (Class_List.class_id=29) AND (User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id)) AS Q GROUP BY Class_List_id1;
```